# SharePoint 2013 Power Pivot

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

We are experiencing a permission issue where users with approves permissions 
(AD domain group - with approve permissions given directly) cannot access the document library containing the excel files, they are able to navigate to the document library but then they get multiple log-in prompts and after entering the credentials numerous times the log-in prompt goes away but the files are not displayed/rendered.

Now when the same is done whilst logged in with a system accounts or setup account everything works as expected and the files is properly rendered.

Additionally when we add the above AD account into a SharePoint security group which has "Approve" permissions, it also works as expected..

Any suggestions on this on getting this fixed? has anyone come across something similar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer investigation the site and power pivot doc library were using unique permissions and set to "restricted read", changing this to "read" resolved the issues...

Not a good idea to use "restricted read" in the first place..

Thanks,